# how could i configure .htacces for slim framework in mac

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim

I have a problem when I want to run my first application with Slim on Mac operating system. I have configured .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And I have configured in httpd.conf to load module rewrite, and I placed index.php in the same directory as .htaccess file.

This is my PHP code (I am using PHP 5.3)

```
<?php                                            
require 'Slim/Slim.php';                         
$app = new Slim();                               
$app->get('hello/:name',function($name) {         
    echo 'Hello' .$name;                         
});                                              
$app->run();                                     
?>
```

When I run it in browser using `http://localhost/slim/hello/test`, I get the error 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm sory i get the solve problem , i don't have `/` character in my code

```
$app->get('hello/:name',function($name){         
    echo 'Hello' .$name;                         
});
```

i'm solve with this code

```
$app->get('/hello/:name',function($name){         
    echo 'Hello' .$name;                         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the rewrite rule should be (with a leading '/' on index.php to say we want index.php in the root directory)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```